# Creating a Task via the PHP Toolkit API

Tags: api, php

have been trying to use the php toolkit to create a task for a while and am stuck.

This is the code I am using currently:

```
$mySforceConnection = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
$mySforceConnection->createConnection(SALESFORCE_WSDL);
$mySforceConnection->login(SALESFORCE_USERNAME, SALESFORCE_PASSWORD.SALESFORCE_SECURITY_TOKEN);

$sObject = new stdclass();
$sObject->Owner = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$sObject->ActivityDate = date('Y-m-d');
$sObject->Description = 'Description';
$sObject->Status = 'Not Started';
$sObject->Priority = 'Normal';
$sObject->Subject = 'Call this guy';
$sObject->Type = 'Other';
$sObject->WhatId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$createResponse = $mySforceConnection->create(array($sObject), 'Task');
```

And this is the error I get:

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [sf:INVALID_TYPE] INVALID_TYPE: Must send a concrete entity type.

Any ideas?

I am trying to create a task attached to a specific lead/account and then I need to create a task that is just attached to a specific user.

Thanks

EDIT:

This is my final solution using the partner wsdl:

```
$fields = array (
    'ActivityDate' => date('Y-m-d'),
    'Status' => 'Not Started',
    'Description' => 'new lead',
    'Subject' => 'call this guy',
    'WhatId' => $account_id,
);

$sObject = new SObject();
$sObject->fields = $fields;
$sObject->type = 'Task';
$createResponse = $mySforceConnection->create(array($sObject));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried switching to the Partner WSDL? I've seen people with the [same issue and switching to use Partner WSDL solved it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326862/salesforce-api-error-on-update-invalid-type-must-send-a-concrete-entity). Unfortunately, I don't know what the root cause is.

Comment: I switched to the partner WSDL and got farther, I'm now getting the error:  
The external foreign key reference does not reference a valid entity: Owner

Comment: Try using OwnerID instead.

Comment: Got: "Assigned To ID: id value of incorrect type:"    Is the owner id the id of the account that the task is attached to or the id of the user?

Comment: OwnerId is the user, WhatId would be for the Account, WhoId would be for the Contact